# set ng-model from property of filtered object array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following:

```
                      <div ng-repeat="scale in LookUpData.AnswerScales | filter:{AnswerScaleTypeId:question.AnswerScaleTypeId}">
                          <label>
                              <input type="radio"
                                     name="QuestionCategoryId{{question.QuestionId}}"
                                     ng-value="scale.AnswerScaleId"
                                     ng-model="(ViewModel.Answers | filter:{QuestionId:question.QuestionId}).AnswerScaleId"
                                     ng-change="scaleQuestionChanged(question.QuestionId, scale.AnswerScaleId)">
                              {{scale.Description}}
                          </label>
                      </div>
```

My question is concerning this line:

```
ng-model="(ViewModel.Answers | filter:{QuestionId:question.QuestionId}).AnswerScaleId"
```

The ViewModel.Answers is a list and I need to dynamically filter it by the QuestionId and then return the AnswerScaleId to set the ng-model with. This is not working. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to see the ng-model just like a "variable" where you are going to assign a value...

I mean, if you have a group of radio buttons and those buttons are for gender selection, the ng-model should be something like

```html
<label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" value="male">
    Male
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="user.gender" ng-value="dataOrFunction">
    Female
  </label><br/>
```

So, in other words (for me) you have to use a "static value" in ng-model (your variable name) an then you are going go assign to that variable wathever you want in the value... So, what you put in value is what is going to be assigned to your ng model.

If you want to use there a dynamic value use ng-value instead of value.

Angularjs ng-model official documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: Jonathan, the problem is that my "user" variable is a list. I only want to get the answer from ViewModel.Answers that pertains to the question being asked. In other words, i want to see if the question being asked has been answered and set the value for it.